# Workmanager stops working, and instantly access dowork method when main activity is open

Tags: android, android-workmanager

My Workmanager needs to send notification every hour, and it is working fine on Nokia and Motorola. However, it is killed by the system on Honor. That's okay, I accepted it, but the problem is that as soon as user opens Main activity, Workmanager instantly access dowork() method and sends notification. Is it possible to delay dowork a bit, or to forbid notification sending if main activity is visible/in foreground and less than minute have passed since main activity was open?

Comment: Did you read the [dontkillmyapp page for Huawei](https://dontkillmyapp.com/huawei)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yeah, my Workmanager is not that important so I let system decide if it wants my workmanager killed or alive. However, I dont like notification appearing instantlly after starting main activity